# Editar arquivo em grupo e em tempo real

Tags: jquery, ajax

Estou querendo desenvolver para um cliente onde ele selecionará um grupo de funcionários e todos poderão editar um arquivo via web. Ele quer estilo como ocorre no Documentos do Google Drive, onde a pessoa digita e a outra pessoa que está em um outro computador consegue visualizar em tempo real ela digitando ou inserindo imagem.

Entendo que isso pode ser feito em Ajax, mas sou muito leigo. Tem algum exemplo no próprio Ajax e até onde isso poderia impactar no servidor, já que o sistema é multi usuário?

Comment: Acho que a melhor alternativa é utilizar WebSockets.

Comment: Olá Diego. Certo. Vou dar uma pesquisada no assunto na internet usando WebSockets, pois sou leigo no assunto. Obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você não mencionou a tecnologia que está utilizando. porém o [`MeteorJS`](https://www.meteor.com) cai como uma luva para resolver o seu problema.

Mas independente do conjunto de tecnologias adotadas por você, a solução com melhor desempenho passa em utilizar uma comunicação com o `Server` utilizando `WebSockets` e no `Front-End` alguma blibioteca Reativa.

No lado do Servidor, vou enumerar alguns exemplos.:

- [ASP.NET WebAPI](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/) + [SignalR](https://www.asp.net/signalr)
- [ExpressJS](https://expressjs.com) + [SocketIO](https://socket.io)
- [ReactPHP + Ratchet](https://reactphp.org)
- [SparkJava](http://sparkjava.com) ([Using WebSockets and Spark to create a real-time chat app](https://sparktutorials.github.io/2015/11/08/spark-websocket-chat.html))

Quanto ao `Front-End`, também tenho algumas sugestões.:

- [VueJS](https://vuejs.org) + [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/)
- [React](https://reactjs.org) + [Redux](https://redux.js.org)

Uma alternativa ao uso de `WebSockets`, seria a utilização do [`PouchDb`](https://pouchdb.com) com [`CouchDb`](http://couchdb.apache.org) e fazer uma [`Replicação dos Dados`](https://pouchdb.com/guides/replication.html), assim como [`escutar todas as alterações`](https://pouchdb.com/guides/changes.html) no Documento, porem neste caso, você teria que fazer uma configuração mais fina para a quantidade de sincronizações.

Comment: Olá Tobias. Na verdade ainda estava pesquisando a melhor solução. Vou dar uma olhada nos links passados por você. Muito obrigado.